# Collect data into curl file from json array

Tags: php, curl

I have a form that is creating a json object

```
Array
(
    [{"full_name":"ttt_tt","company_name":"ttt","email":"joe@coffee_com","free_trial":"Yes","quota":"","contract":0,"per_gb":"$_115","per_month":null,"wanaccel":"No"}] => 
)
```

How do I get this into a curl file to send out?

Is there a way to send it directly to a php curl file?

Comment: What do you mean by a curl file?

Comment: This may clarify.  After submit I am trying to capture user data into a curl data array.      

How would I pull the data into the curl file?

Comment: `curl` is a library for making HTTP requests to another server from PHP. Are you saying that you're going to use this input as the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` data when the script makes a call to an API?

Comment: I don't understand the contents of the array you show. You have a JSON object as the key, with no value. Why have you done it that way? Why don't you just send the JSON object by itself?

Comment: Why are you sending JSON froma form at all? When a form posts data, it's usually in URL-encoded format, and PHP will decode that to an associative array in `$_POST`.

Comment: You are correct.  Im still learning and I make silly decisions.  If i just use php how would I pull in the form data to the correct array field?

Comment: Use `json_parse($json_string, true)` to convert it to an array. Then use that array in `curl_setopt`.